# Dúvida Comparar Valores Retornados de Webservice JSON

Tags: php, html, jquery, json

Tenho um site em Wordpress e nele estou consumindo um Web Service, criei uma função para filtrar os campeonatos com base em algumas informações: 

Sexo : M 

Modalidade : 2 

Categoria : 4

Se todas forem verdadeiras, ele retorna o nome do respectivo campeonato e imprime na tela dentro de uma **div** data-toggle do bootstrap, a função está correta, mas eu precisava que dentro do conteúdo desse data-toggle, ele comparasse dois valores retornados de urls diferentes em JSON:

$api_resultados['campeonato]
$api_campeonatos['codigo']

Se estes valores forem iguais, precisava imprimir o resultado dos jogos do respectivo campeonato dentro da **div tables**, em formato de tabela:

**Mandante x Visitante**, **placar** e **data**

eu estou tentando da seguinte forma, mas sem sucesso, se puderem me ajudar, ficarei grato!

**Puxa valores do campeonato e imprime os nomes se verdadeiro:**

```
<?php 
    $api_campeonatos = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL';
    $campeonatos = wp_remote_get( $api_campeonatos );
    $campeonatos_data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $campeonatos ), true );
    $retorno_campeonatos = array(); // <- mudar para array

    if($campeonatos_data){
        foreach($campeonatos_data as $row){
            if(!is_array($row)){
                //$retorno = $retorno.'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
            }else{
                if($row['sexo'] == 'M' && $row['modalidade'] == 2 && $row['categoria'] == 4){
                    $retorno_campeonatos[] = array('valor' => '<td>'.$row['nome'].'</td>', 'id' => $row['codigo']); // <--- adiciona
                }   
            }   
        }
    }
?>


<script>

$(function(){

    var html = '';

    var html2 = '';

    <?php foreach($retorno_campeonatos as $valor){ ?>

        html += '<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#bloco-<?php echo $valor['id'];?>" role="tab"><?php echo $valor['valor'];?></a>';

        html2 += '<div class="tab-pane" id="bloco-<?php echo $valor['id'];?>" role="tabpanel"><div id="tables></div></div>';

    <?php } ?>

    $('#myList').html(html);

    $('#tabList').html(html2);
});

</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">   
        <div id="contents">
            <div class="list-group" id="myList" role="tablist">
            </div>

            <div id="tabList" class="tab-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Puxa o resultado dos campeonatos e imprime a tabela:**

```
<?php 
    $api_resultados = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/resultados?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
    $resultados = wp_remote_get( $api_resultados );
    $resultados_data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $resultados ), true );
    $retorno_resultados = array(); // <- mudar para array

    if($resultados_data){
        foreach($resultados_data as $row => $campeonatos_data){
            if(!is_array($row)){
                //$retorno = $retorno.'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
            }else{
                if($row['campeonato'] == $campeonatos_data['codigo']){
                    $retorno_resultados[] = array('val' => '<td>'.$row['mandante'].'</td>'); // <--- adiciona
                }   
            }   
        }
    }
?>

<script>

$(function(){

    var html3 = '';

    <?php foreach($retorno_resultados as $val){ ?>

        html3 += '<td><?php echo $val['mandante'];?>x<?php echo $val['visitante'];?></td>';

    <?php } ?>

    $('#tables').html(html3);

});

</script>
```

**Retorno Campeonatos:**

```
  {
"codigo": "17",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE OURO",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "6",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
  {
"codigo": "19",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE OURO",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "4",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
  {
"codigo": "18",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE PRATA",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "4",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
```

**Retorno Resultados**

```
 {
"codigo": "32",
"campeonato": "18",
"data": "2018-09-25 00:00:00",
"horario": "18",
"local": "4",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "7",
"visitante": "3",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "4",
"obs": null
},
  {
"codigo": "25",
"campeonato": "19",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"horario": "19",
"local": "9",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "2",
"visitante": "6",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "9",
"obs": null
},
```

Comment: Qual o problema? Não entendi

Comment: eu adicionei um novo chamado de url, que retorna os resultados dos jogos do campeonato, no código eu tentei comprar os valores json das urls _$api_resultados['campeonato]_
e _$api_campeonatos['codigo']_, se os valores forem iguais, imprimir o jogo com _"mandante"_, _"visitante", _data_ e _placar_, na **div id="tables", não da erro, mas não retorna nenhum valor na tela...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está querendo utilizar `$val['visitante']` sem estar disponível no array `$retorno_resultados`. Além disso, você está usando a chave 'mandante' que também não está disponível.

Outro erro está no seu `foreach` aonde você está tentando comparar coisas diferentes e que até não existem dentro do array.

após [conversas no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80942/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-miguel-campos)

**Solução**

```
<?php

$api_resultados = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/resultados?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
$resultado = file_get_contents($api_resultados);
$resultado = json_decode($resultado, true);

$api_campeonato = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
$campeonato = file_get_contents($api_campeonato);
$campeonato = json_decode($campeonato, true);

//print_r($campeonatos_data);

$retorno_resultados = array();

foreach($campeonato as $camp){
    foreach($resultado as $result){
        if(isset($camp['codigo']) && isset($result['campeonato']) && $camp['codigo'] == $result['campeonato']){
            $retorno_resultados[] = array(
                'mandante' => '<td>'.$result['mandante'].'</td>', 
                'visitante' => '<td>'.$result['visitante'].'</td>', 
                'id' => $camp['codigo'],
                'data' => '<td>'.$camp['data'],
                'placar1n' => '<td>'.$result['placar1n'].'</td>',
                'placar2n' => '<td>'.$result['placar2n'].'</td>',
                'placar1p' => '<td>'.$result['placar1p'].'</td>',
                'placar2p' => '<td>'.$result['placar2p'].'</td>',
                'placar1s' => '<td>'.$result['placar1s'].'</td>',
                'placar2s' => '<td>'.$result['placar2s'].'</td>'
            ); // <--- adiciona
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
<script>

$(function(){

    var html2 = '';

    <?php foreach($retorno_resultados as $val){ ?>

        html2 += '<div class="tab-pane" id="bloco-<?php echo $val['id'];?>" role="tabpanel"><td><?php echo $val['mandante'];?></td></div>';

    <?php } ?>

    $('#tabList').html(html2);

});

</script>
```

Comment: ah sim, estou começando a pegar a syntax, ainda não retornou nenhum valor :(

Comment: @MiguelCampos tem um erro no seu foreach. Porque você quer comparar isso: `$row['campeonato'] == $campeonatos_data['codigo']`?

Comment: se esses dois valores forem iguais eu preciso exibir uma tabela com os retornos da url "resultados" por exemplo, se o campeonatos codigo : 19, for igual o resultados campeonato : 19, montar uma tabela com os valores do resultados, que seria o mandante, visitante, placar e data

Comment: Ah ta... Calma ae. Você misturou as coisas. Eles estão em urls diferentes né?

Comment: isso, são urls diferentes

Comment: @MiguelCampos tenta agora.

Comment: Nada ainda, na função do campeonato, estou tentando imprimir o conteúdo da seguinte forma _html2 += '<div class="tab-pane" id="bloco-<?php echo $valor['id'];?>" role="tabpanel"><div id="tables"></div></div>';_, e um script no "resultados" pra inserir a tabela dentro desse div "tables", isso está correto?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80942/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-miguel-campos).